# EditText field Not working properly in Listview

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I'm developing an `order-taking` app in which user enters quantity against the product that he/she needs. Their is `editText` field in listview against each product.

The problem which I'm facing is that when user enters the quantity suppose in 3rd row of `listview` the quantity which he/she enters repeats every 10 rows.

I'm adding all the products in arraylist named as **`nextValueOf`** and sending it to next activity. Please see the code and tell me where I'm doing wrong

```
public class TweetListAdaptor extends ArrayAdapter<Medicine> implements Filterable {

        private ArrayList<Medicine> mOriginalValues = new ArrayList<Medicine>(); // Original Values
        private ArrayList<Medicine> mDisplayedValues = new ArrayList<Medicine>();    // Values to be displayed
        LayoutInflater inflater;

        public TweetListAdaptor(Context context,ArrayList<Medicine> products) {
                  super(context, R.layout.medicine_list_info, products);
                  this.mOriginalValues = products;
                  this.mDisplayedValues = products;
                  inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mDisplayedValues.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Medicine getItem(int position)
        {
            return mDisplayedValues.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }


       public class ViewHolder {
            private TextView productName;
            private TextView productType;
            private EditText productQuantity;

            public ViewHolder(View v) {
                 this.productName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textViewProductID);
                 this.productType = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textViewProductName);
                 this.productQuantity= (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.editTextEnterQuantity);

                // this.date = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.date);
                // this.status = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.staus);
            }
        }

       @Override  
       public int getViewTypeCount() {
           return getCount();
       }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            final ViewHolder holder;
                View v = convertView;
                if (v == null) {
                        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)
                                getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.medicine_list_info, null);
                        holder = new ViewHolder(v);
                        v.setTag(holder);
                }else {
                    holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
                    }

                final Medicine o = getItem(position);
                if (o != null) {

                    holder.productName.setText(o._product_name);
                    NumberFormat nm = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();

                    holder.productType.setText(nm.format(o._price));

                    holder.productQuantity.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                            if(!hasFocus){
                                final EditText Caption = (EditText) v;
                                Caption.setFocusable(true);
                                holder.productQuantity.setFocusable(true);

                                try{
                                    o._quantity = Integer.parseInt(Caption.getText().toString());

                                }catch(NumberFormatException nfe) {
                                    System.out.println("Could not parse " + nfe);
                                 }

                                if(o._quantity != 0 ){

                                Medicine olx = new Medicine(o._id,o._product_Code,o._product_name,o._price, o._quantity );
                                String ods =  "ID: "+ o.get_id()  +"Name :" + o.get_product_name() +" ,Price: " + o.get_price() + " ,Quantity: " + o.get_quantity(); ;
                                Log.d("Problem Is here :", ods);

                                nextValuesOf.add(olx);  

                                }

                            }   
                        }
                    }); 
           }
                return v;      
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the due to `ListView` recycle the same view for other child items.

You need to change your adapter to say listview that your item view are different view type,  else you will see the entered text in other list items of `EditText`.

`Override` `getViewTypeCount` in custom Adapter as return the item count

```
 public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return getCount();
  }
```

And also change the getItemViewType to return a unique id , e.g., position is unique number

```
 public int getItemViewType(int position) {
     return position;
 }
```

Comment: i have shared my custom adapter class ... please tell me where should i put this

Comment: Add Inside TweetListAdaptor class. You already have getViewTypeCount. Just add only override getItemViewType